# CSS Image Gallery Autoplay

Tags: image, gallery

I have added an image gallery to my [website](http://cgscomputing.com/team21/home) that I'm working on for an Assignment. As you can see, on the main page, I have a CSS Image Gallery, that works perfectly fine, but I was looking for a way to make the images scroll from 1 to 4, and back to 1 again, over the course of about 1 - 2 minutes.

I've tried using css animations, but to no avail. I don't know much javascript, but if the answer is in javascript, that is perfectly fine.

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: Use one of great slideshow JQuery plugins, e.g. http://amazingslider.com/

Comment: That isn't what i'm looking for, because I quite like the design i have for the gallery at the moment. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Keep design, and use this, then: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ (my favourite slideshow plugin) Extremely easy to implement.